# How to implement ehcache for apache shiro in spring boot correctly and working with ehcache for spring together?

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache, shiro

I'm using apache shiro 1.4.0 in **Spring Boot 2.1.0** for security management. In both of shiro and spring, I need use the ehCache.

For shiro, I want to use the feature of locking account when error input times of password.

I have a `CacheConfig` class to integrate the cache manager;
Then I integrated `CacheManager` into `ShiroConfig`;
Then I implement the `RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher`;
At last, run application, Spring Boot start failed.

**references in the POM.XML**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Shiro ehCache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>``
```

**CacheConfig class**

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig  {
    @Bean(name = "ehCache")
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cacheBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("configs/ehcache/ehcache.xml"));
        cacheBean.setShared(false);
        return cacheBean;
    }

    @Bean("springCacheManager")
    public EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager(@Qualifier("ehCache") CacheManager ehcacheManager) {
        EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager(ehcacheManager);
        return ehCacheCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean("shiroCacheManager")
    public EhCacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheManager();  
ehCacheManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
            return ehCacheManager;
        }
    }
```

**ShiroConfig class related with ehCache reference**

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {  
    ...  

    @Bean(name = "securityManager")
    public SecurityManager securityManager(@Qualifier("rptShiroRealm")RptShiroRealm rptShiroRealm, EhCacheManager ehCacheManager) {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager defaultWebSecurityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        // Setting Realm
        defaultWebSecurityManager.setRealm(rptShiroRealm);
        // Set Shiro to use Cache
        defaultWebSecurityManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager);

        return defaultWebSecurityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManager ehCacheManager(CacheManager shiroCacheManager) {
        EhCacheManager em = new EhCacheManager();
        // Convert ehCacheManager to Shiro wrapped ehCacheManager object,
        // this make spring to manage cache
        em.setCacheManager(shiroCacheManager);
        return em;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Custome RptShiroRealm class**

```
@Component(value = "rptShiroRealm")
public class RptShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void initCredentialsMatcher() {
        RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher matcher = new RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher();

        matcher.setHashAlgorithmName(ShiroConstant.HASH_ALGORITHM);
        matcher.setHashIterations(ShiroConstant.HASH_INTERATIONS);
        matcher.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(
            ShiroConstant.STORED_CREDENTIALS_HEX_ENCODED); 
        setCredentialsMatcher(matcher);
    } 
    ...
}
```

**The last, RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher class**

```
public class RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher extends HashedCredentialsMatcher {
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager shiroCacheManager;
    private Ehcache passwordRetryCache;

    public RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher() {
        passwordRetryCache = shiroCacheManager.getCache("passwordRetryCache");
}

    @Override
    public boolean doCredentialsMatch(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo info) {
        String username = (String)token.getPrincipal();
        //retry count + 1
        Element element = passwordRetryCache.get(username);
        if(element == null) {
            element = new Element(username , new AtomicInteger(0));
            passwordRetryCache.put(element);
        }
        AtomicInteger retryCount = (AtomicInteger)element.getObjectValue();
        if(retryCount.incrementAndGet() > 5) {
            //if retry count > 5 throw
            throw new ExcessiveAttemptsException();
        }

        boolean matches = super.doCredentialsMatch(token, info);
        if(matches) {
            //clear retry count
            passwordRetryCache.remove(username);
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

When I start the application, it throws stack exception as below:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-27 16:19:45.629 ERROR 10484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in class path resource [com/test/marpt/common/components/shiro/bean/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'shiroFilterFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [com/test/marpt/common/components/shiro/bean/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rptShiroRealm': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.test.marpt.LxMaRptApplication.main(LxMaRptApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [com/test/marpt/common/components/shiro/bean/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rptShiroRealm': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rptShiroRealm': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.test.marpt.common.components.shiro.bean.RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher.<init>(RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.test.marpt.common.components.shiro.RptShiroRealm.initCredentialsMatcher(RptShiroRealm.java:190) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

How can I fix the NPE...I dont't know why it takes out...can any one help me to fix it out, Thanks very much?
I found the crux of which causes exception is in my custom `ShrioRealm`, where I reference `RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher`, I can't use it.

Comment: Are you upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5 or writing this from scratch?

Comment: Hi, [Brian Demers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6415199/brian-demers), I created the project from Ideal with Spring Boot Init tool

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it seems like you need to inject a `RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher` instead of managing the object outside of Spring, as you are autowiring objects inside of it.